# Microsoft Graph API Reports - throttling

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, report, throttling

As per the information provided by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#microsoft-graph-reports-service-limits), the throttling limit for Reports service of Microsoft Graph API, per app, per tenant is 14 requests in 10 minutes.

But from my application, I make 5 requests simultaneously (using multi-threading) and I am getting the TenantThrottleThresholdExceeded exception.

I am wondering why would I get the throttling exception for just 5 requests?
Anybody else is facing this?

Please help.

Comment: Which reports are you requesting?

Comment: @baywet.. I am requesting Outlook reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook APIs have a limit of 4 concurrent requests. This has an impact on reporting when asking reports for Outlook objects. Make sure you don't send your requests in parallel, or reduce parallelization to 4 and you shouldn't get throttled anymore

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. May I know where can I find these limits? Because I'm planning to use reports for other reports as well, like Teams, Share point etc..

Comment: On the same page you linked, look at Outlook service limits for example. SharePoint doesn't publish their limits though