# Throttling limits for MS Graph APIs against Sharepoint lists: delta (retrieving items and monitoring changes) and item insertion

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to understand what the actual limits for our current scenario are, in which several concurrent requests will retrieve and update Sharepoint list items.  What are the limitations around the number of concurrent requests?

The closest thread I found out would be [Microsoft Graph API Reports - throttling - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324420/microsoft-graph-api-reports-throttling) that mentions the throttling limit for Reports service of Microsoft Graph API, per app, per tenant is 14 requests in 10 minutes and there are limitations around the number of concurrent requests. Ex. Outlook API have limit of 4 concurrent requests.

Thanks,
Nicholas.

I got throttled after a large number of item insertions (>2k+) but wanted to better understand the limitations of the scenario.